# Gibbon GEM: API wrapper for MailChimp's API - How to implement with a DELETE method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

The Gibbon Gem seems quite versatile. I managed to use it and create GET requests. For example, I am able to do a GET request and get all information on an order on Mailchimp. But I somehow can't make a request with the method DELETE.

- MailChimp Documentation on the API Order: [Documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/orders/#)
- Gibbon Mailchimp API Wrapper [Documentation](https://github.com/amro/gibbon)

So here is my code:

```
gibbon.ecommerce.stores("YourStoreName")
                .orders("orderNumber")
                .retrieve(headers: {"method": "delete"})
```

The result is a GET request and a huge JSON with all information on the order. If I run the exact same request again, I get the same information back (even though I wanted to delete it)

Anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing this answer I just found the solution myself.

The correct solution would be to use the .delete method (and not trying to specify the method in the header)

```
gibbon.ecommerce.stores("YourStoreName")
                .orders("orderNumber")
                .delete
```

Keeping the answer here, because maybe someone else will find this useful.